# Match base url regex

Tags: regex

Examples:

```
http://example.com ---> http://example.com
ftp://username:password@example.com ---> ftp://username:password@example.com
http://example.com/path/to/somehwere ---> http://example.com
http://example.co.uk ---> http://example.co.uk
example.co.uk ---> example.co.uk
example.co.uk?user=John&pass=1234 ---> example.com.uk
```

I tried this:

```
.*?(:\/{2})?.*?(?=\/|$|\?)
```

its working for the urls without protocols but cause of the `(?=\/|$|\?)` it stops at `http:`

Cany you help me fix my regex? or suggest better?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This lookahead based regex should for you:

```
^.+?[^\/:](?=[?\/]|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tkdQBX/1)

Lookahead assertion `(?=[?\/]|$)` makes sure to stop matching when next character is `/` or `?` or there is line end.

Comment: awesome! what about localhost or port#?

Comment: @JDPeckham: I have added a demo that matches `localhost` and port as well.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(http://|ftp://|https://)?[^/\?]*$
```

Good Luck!