# Get application url using angular 6

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I have an angular6 application and I am using the same code in different domains. Few of them are in the root of the domain and some are uploaded in folders and subfolders.

example :

```
  example1.com
  example2.com/myapp
  example3.com/myapp/v1
```

For some additional purposes, I need the base URL of the application. For this, I have tried `location.origin` , but the problem is, It returns only the domain part if we are using subfolders.

Currently, I am using the below code for getting the URL in each page.

```
this.base_url = location.href.split('order_confirmation')[0];
```

This will work if the current route is start with "order_confirmation", But if the base URL needed for another page, I need to explore it with the route string and get the URL from that array.
Is there any better method available in angular 6 for getting the URL directly?

Comment: Note that AngularJs is Angular 1, I edited your tags (yeah, it's confuse naming, not SO fault though)

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with angular anyway (neither angularjs, nor angular in general). Did you check this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098739/match-base-url-regex . You may just want to get the entire URL and use a regex to get the base URL... or this, really: https://www.regextester.com/105075

Comment: @Kaddath I have added an answer, I got this working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with the following lines of code,

```
import {PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';
export class ConfirmationComponent implements OnInit {
  public base_url;
   constructor(private platformlocation: PlatformLocation){
    this.base_url = location.origin + this.platformlocation.getBaseHrefFromDOM();
   }
}
```